# "cursive" and "printed" writing

Tags: traducción, escritura

In English, we describe writing as either cursive/longhand (joined letters) or printed (block letters). What Spanish words are there to describe these concepts? And how common is the use of cursive in Spanish-speaking countries compared to English-speaking ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called:

> Cursive = Cursiva o Manuscrita
>   Printed = Molde o De Imprenta

As far as how much is cursive is used I can tell you that where I come from (Mexico), I write in cursive and most people are surprised to see my handwriting, so I guess not too common.

Comment: Just a small addition... In Spain I'd say that we wouldn't understand "Manuscrita" as "Cursive". For us, "Manuscrita" is "hand-written" (without specifying any kind of style). Besides that, the usage is the same as Sergio said. (Cursive = Cursiva, Printed = Molde o De Imprenta)

Comment: I would use "letra ligada" for cursive, but maybe is regional?

Comment: *Itálica* o *bastardilla* are also used for *cursive*.

Comment: I'm afraid some commenters are misunderstanding the English word *cursive*.